# How to integrate vue project into existing react project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js

How to integrate vue project that also has own routes into existing react project?

For example, my vue project has routes /, /en, /blog

I need to open vue project in my existing react project on page /vue

vue/en

vue/blog

etc.

And I want to vue can use my react components and constants.

Comment: You shouldn't mix front-end libraries. It doesn't work well. You won't be able to share components since they have fundamentally different renders.

Comment: Read about micro-frontends